# Magento 2: I Want To Make Custom Products Tab On Home Page

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, custom, tabs

I trying to make custom dynamic tab on home page but when do that I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: tab is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1200)`

Here is my code I don't know whats is the issue in my code:

```
<?php 
    $categoryIds = [];
    $cateCount = count($block->categoryCollection()); 
    $i=1;
    $k=1;
?>

<div class="tab">
    <?php foreach ($block->categoryCollection() as $category): ?>        
        <?php $categoryIds[] = $category->getData('entity_id'); ?>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, <?= 'tab-'.$i; ?>)"><?= 'tab-'.$i; ?></button>
        <?php $i+=1; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php for($j=1;$j<=$cateCount;$j++):?>
    <div id="<?= 'tab-'.$j; ?>" class="tabcontent">
        <?php
            foreach ($block->productCollection($categoryIds) as $product):
                echo $product->getName();
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

**Js**

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it's working I just add single `colan` like this:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, `<?= 'tab-'.$i; ?>`)"><?= 'tab-'.$i; ?></button>
```